# Does the tensor algebra $T(V)$ of $V$ isomorphic to the symmetric algebra of the free Lie algebra over $V$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, hopf-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $T(V)$ be the [tensor algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra) over $V$.

Do we have $T(V) \cong S(Lie(V))$ as a graded vector space? Here $S(Lie(V))$ is the symmetric algebra of the free Lie algebra over $V$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, by PBW, in characteristic zero.

Comment: Is there something like "the free algebra over a vector space"? If you consider $V$ just as a set, the answer to your question is obviously no: $T(V)$ depends of course on the vector space structure.

Comment: To complete Qiaochu's comment, the key fact is that $T(V) $ is isomorphic as an Hopf algebra to the enveloping algebra of the free Lie algebra on $V$.

Comment: I think the question is a bit ambiguous: here each $K$ of $T$, $S$ and $\mathrm{Lie}$ is considered as a mapping a graded vector space $W$ to a graded algebra $K(W)$ with $K(W)_1=W$ as graded vector space, and the original vector space $V$ is entirely graded in degree 1 (but this should work without this restriction, namely in the "universal" case when $V$ of dimension $d$ is graded in $\mathbf{Z}^d$ with independent weights. (As asked now, another interpretation would be to put $\mathrm{Lie}(V)$ in degree 1, but then the result fails since $T(V)_1$ is finite-dim but not $S(Lie(V))_1$.)